# Wrong icon rendering

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've downloaded the font awesome css file and included it into my page, but the icons where displaying wrong. See [image: pic]

When I use the cnd version online, it works just fine.

What can be the problem here ?

Comment: Most likely you have the wrong path to the font files. Check your error console

Comment: Damn. Of course, the font files. Make it an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to upload the font files to your server and set the correct path in the font-awesome css file.